# How to put if and then statements while creating snowflakes in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

--im a beginner ..so im not sure how to make sure that the snowflakes don't overlap. Thanks!

```
import turtle

turtle.right(90)

turtle.penup()

turtle.goto(-700,300)

turtle.pendown()

def snowflakebranch(n):

    turtle.forward(n*4)
    for i in range(3):
        turtle.backward(n)
        turtle.right(45)
        turtle.forward(n)
        turtle.backward(n)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(n)
        turtle.backward(n)
        turtle.right(45)

def snowflake(n):

    for i in range(8):
        snowflakebranch(n)
        turtle.backward(n)
        turtle.right(45)

import random

turtle.colormode(255)

turtle.tracer(0)

for i in range(35):

    r = random.randint(0, 255)
    g = random.randint(0, 255)
    b = random.randint(0, 255)
    turtle.color(r, g, b)
    x = random.randint(-500, 500)
    y = random.randint(-500, 500)
    d = random.randint(6, 16)
    snowflake(d)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    #turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.pendown()


    turtle.update()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is a Q& A site, no a "do my homework" for me site. Please add some more details about what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried, etc. If you want, edit the question and we will try out best.

Comment: Think about how you would test whether your N snowflakes would overlap if you drew them all out on the display. How would you test for overlap other than visual inspection? That should lead you to a test of whether the center point for a new snowflake is acceptable or if you need to go back to the randint well....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to calculate a bounding rectangle (or circle) for each snowflake.  Save these as a list or a set.  Whenever you plan to make a new snowflake, first check if its bounding rectangle (or circle) overlaps with the bounds of any previous snowflakes.  If it does, don't draw it.  If it doesn't, draw it and save its bounds too.  An incomplete outline of this approach:

```
import turtle
import random

def snowflakebranch(n):

    turtle.forward(n * 4)

    for _ in range(3):
        turtle.backward(n)
        turtle.right(45)
        turtle.forward(n)
        turtle.backward(n)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(n)
        turtle.backward(n)
        turtle.right(45)

def snowflake(n):

    for _ in range(8):
        snowflakebranch(n)
        turtle.backward(n)
        turtle.right(45)

def overlapping(bounds_list, bounds):
    for previous in bounds_list:
        if overlap(previous, bounds):
            return True

    return False

def overlap(b1, b2):
    # return True or False if these two rectanges or circles overlap
    pass

turtle.penup()

turtle.colormode(255)

turtle.tracer(0)

previous_bounds = []

i = 0

while i < 35:

    x = random.randint(-500, 500)
    y = random.randint(-500, 500)
    turtle.goto(x, y)

    r = random.randint(0, 255)
    g = random.randint(0, 255)
    b = random.randint(0, 255)
    turtle.color(r, g, b)

    turtle.pendown()

    d = random.randint(6, 16)

    # work out the bounding rectangle or circle based on 'd', 'x' & 'y'
    # e.g. (x, y, width & height) or (x, y, radius)
    bounds = ( ... )  

    if not overlapping(previous_bounds, bounds):

        snowflake(d)

        turtle.update()

        previous_bounds.append(bounds)

        i += 1

    turtle.penup()

turtle.done()
```

An image of non-overlapping snowflakes using the above logic with the bounding circles also displayed:

[image]

I actually like the look of your overlapping snowflakes.  Even if you want overlap, the above logic will allow you to control how much overlap.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed explanation.